# Select2 failed load selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 plugin for PHP programs,

I got sometimes I can load the value with this way

```
$('#item_codePop').val(itemCodePop);
$("#item_codePop").trigger('change');
```

But, that only works for a data from `add` function and it not work when I get the data from `load` function.

at my `add` function, I always call this

```
$('#item_codePop').val('');
$("#item_codePop").trigger('change');
```

that's the only different between Edit data from `add` function and the `load` function. Is that impact something ?

Comment: Can you provide fiddle to demonstrate what's not working? If you call load function on page load, it must be in the `$(document).ready(function()});` block.

Comment: the load function is not triggred from `$(document).ready(function(){});`. But it's call from event when another select change thier value...

Comment: I need a database to simulate it.. because it's load data from the database.. maybe i can provide the code to jsfiddle

Comment: Fiddle will help to identify the problem correctly. You could use static array or JSON data responded to demonstrate with fiddle.

Comment: Ok, I will try to edit the code first...

Comment: Oh sorry. It's too hard for me, I'm never use the jsfilled before, and It's a lot change to code to make it work with jsfilled.. Maybe there's another way to simulate it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must create variable for your object like following and then trigger change on it...

```
var $example = $(".your_Class").select2();

$(".your_button").on("click", function () {
      $("#item_codePop").val("").trigger("change");
})
```

[visit this link](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple)